# is that private and public access modifier make difference in performance?

Tags: java, c++, class, oop, member

I think we have to use correct modifier on member variable to achieve modularity, but curious about effect of access modifiers of Class Members on performance of application.

If my program is small, then what if I use all member variable public?

Comment: The answer could be different depending on language, please pick one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both C++ and Java the modifier itself does not directly affect performance: it is there during the compilation stage to enforce separation of concerns, but there is no trace of the modifier in the compiled (object) code. However, using accessor and mutator functions to refer to a member variable will in theory impose some minor performance penalties. Even then, in C++ those calls can be inlined by the compiler, removing the penalty completely. @Peter Lawrey mentions in the comments that similar optimisations are available for Java.

Thus, use whatever leads to a cleaner design, since any performance implications are arguable.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect explanation.

Comment: Java can inline "virtual" accessor methods even if they are compiled after the program starts.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ the access modifiers have no effect on the performance of an application, it's all about access/visibility. They are a compile-time only concept, and there's no run-time component or checks.

Comment: Thanks for answer, and what about other languages? I am working with java.

Comment: @totaloverdose Then why did you tag with C++? Java and C++ might look similar at a glance, but are two totally different languages with totally different semantics.

Comment: ok, I thought this is belongs to basic object oriented concept. I will update the question. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

It seriously has no effect in Java! 
Effectiveness is a common talk between friends and colleagues but in the end we all try to maximize effectiveness with the wrong way... 
Most problems with effective coding is many lines of code (You wouldn't like to see how many...) and logic errors that go in unnecessary loops (Not ultimate loops but unnecessary nontheless let's say... frequent checkers for example that can be otherwise be called by other events)

Everybody has been where you are! 
But you won't find much down there ;p